# how to naming class, struct, enum and union

Tags: c++, class, struct, enums, naming

Two examples:

I want define time:

```
class Time
{
    month(){...} 

    year(){...}

    private:

    time_t a;
}

struct Time    
{int year; int month;}
```

But c++ can not allow define same name. So how to define `struct` name? Add prefix or suffix, e.g. `STime` or `TimeStruct`

Similarly, I want to define color:

```
class Color
{
  int color;

  red(){...}
}

enum Color
{
    e_red,

    e_green
}
```

There is a name conflict too. So how to define `enum` name? Add prefix or suffix, e.g. `EColor` or `ColorEnum`.

There is name conflict using `union` too. So how to avoid `struct`, `enum` and `union` name conflict with class name? Add prefix or suffix?

Comment: Cant understand ur question...can u xplain wat u r trying to do?

Comment: The same name shouldn't be appropriate for both a simple data holder and a complex class.  Anyway, C++ has this thing called a *namespace*.

Comment: If you want to name two different things the same name, you're not conceptualizing your program right.

Comment: OK, I will ask another question to replace it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [namespace](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/) to limit the scope

```
namespace MyClass
{
   class Time { ... };
}

namespace MyStruct
{
  struct Time { ... };
}

...
MyClass::Time c;
MyStruct::Time s;
...
```